# Is "user-interaction" a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [user-interaction](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interaction) tag is one of our most common tags but it's not a term I've ever heard before this site. I'm thinking maybe people use it as a synonym of [interaction-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interaction-design) but user interaction sounds more like a way of saying "human computer interaction," which on this site is a uselessly broad tag.

Should we nix or synonmize this tag? I'm learning towards nixing it as I bet a lot of people just type "user" into the tag bar and see [user-interaction](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interaction) pop up and think "gee, that applies to me!"

Comment: Also, [tag:user-behavior].

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney that at least has some meaning, but I think psychology is a more fitting tag in most cases. It's also broad but not used very often, I guess i'm one of the few that thinks of most of this as being a matter of psychology =) http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology

Comment: Yeah, it should probably be changed to [tag:psychology], [tag:gamification], or [tag:behavioral-economics], or just deleted, depending on the question.

Comment: Just noticed that one's even MORE common, and will require some cleanup probably. This one I think's pretty safe to wholesale delete, as Rahul said most of these questions are tagged with more descriptive tags anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If it means what I think it means, eg. the way users interact with software, then it's too broad. It looks like it's on quite a few questions that are also tagged with things like [button](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/button) and [forms](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms). Those are specific and in line with the nature of the questions. So I think it might be okay to get rid of it and rely on those more specific tags instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably fair that "user-interaction" is too broad. I think "interaction-design" focuses it far more on the design of the interactions.

User-behaviour - as mentioned by @Patrick - is probably sufficiently different, as it should be about how users behave - more anthropological or psychological. I am all for leaving some of these similar words, as it can help questioners to think about where their question sits. The user-interaction should fit with 90% of the questions, and so does not seem helpful in that.